# PHP Counter Issue

Tags: php, counter

I have a counter that should be incrementing by 1 but yet it is incrementing by 2.  I have the controller and view.  It's a simple exercise but I'm not sure why it's incrementing by 2.  Anyone have any ideas?

http://screencast.com/t/w9w7GndQK

CONTROLLER

```
function setCount($fileName = 'counter.txt') {
if (file_exists($fileName)) {

    //read the value
    $handle = fopen($fileName, 'r');

    // increment it by one
    $count = (int) fread($handle, 20) + 1;

    // write the new value
    $handle = fopen($fileName, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $count);

    // close the file
    fclose($handle);
} else {

    // create the file
    $handle = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
    $count = 1;

    // set a default value of 1
    fwrite($handle, $count);
    fclose($handle);
}


return $count;
}

$count = setCount();

require('index.tmpl.php');
```

VIEW:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Counter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#">
</head>
<body>
    <p>You are the <?php echo $count; ?>visitor to this website.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if it's going up by 2, then the function's being called twice...

Comment: if those are two seperate files, you need to show us your full code for VIEW.

Comment: I don't think it related to your issue, but you are missing an `fclose($handle)` in your first `if` before the second `fopen` call.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have shown you my full code for the view.

Comment: so how are you callng the function? you didn't answer my full question though, being the former and not the latter.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$count = setCount();` it's in the code he provided.

Comment: @MarcB, Not necessarily.  Look at this - http://screencast.com/t/ct2REKy9N9dO

In the file it shows one number, but on the actual page it shows a different number.

Comment: you also have no locking, so if you have two+ instances of the script running in parallel, you can/will lose counts as the two instances overwrite each other's updates.

Comment: is there a special reason why you want to use a text-based counter rather than a database? Looking at your other questions, seems you already have a database, so why this? text-based counters are a bit of a hassle too. TBH, I tried fixing your code and for the life of me, I couldn't get it to work. You'll probably spend less time (as will I), just using a script that's already setup for text-based and I have a few already in my scripts library. Otherwise, either try and see what you can do and post your own answer, or wait for someone else to see what they can do. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using a text-file for this is bad practice and can result in inconsestent behavior. For example, when two visitors access the site at the same time: Visitor 1 open the file, increase the stored value lets say 5 to 6, and before it can save its changes another visitor open the file and do the same. Now a visitor is dropped because in both cases the counter will only incease once thought there where two visitors.

Instead you should use a database like MySQL to store the data. This make it also easy to build a more detailed counter. For example, you can get stats about how much people visited the page per day or which are the most frequented hours. It is also possible to track details about the users system (e.g. useragent which show what browser + version and operating system the user has) or log the referer to get informed from which pages your visitors came to you.

A simple counter-table could be consist of the timestamp and the ip-adress of the visitor.

```
CREATE TABLE pageviews(
    datetime INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);
```

To track a visitor you need to run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO pageviews
SET datetime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
    ip = "' . $db->escape( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) . '"
```

Now you can extract the data like you want. For a total-counter you can simpy do a COUNT(*) on the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalViews
FROM pageviews
```

You're free to display what you want, e.g. group by day as I mentioned before.

Comment: The main gist of this answer is that by simply using something like MySQL in stead of a file, you've somehow solved all concurrency issues, while it actally the same concurrency challanges which are _not_ overcome by this answer.

Comment: Personally, the OP "should" be using a database and not wasting their time or fiddling with text-based counters, seeing they're already used to working with a database, therefore I upvoted this answer.

Comment: However, this answer shouldd also include/use an UPDATE method in order to properly increment the given row, to say `UPDATE table set counter = counter +1 WHERE col_x = 'something'` type of thing.